# what's the benefits of turning off `PRAGMA trusted_schema` in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

quoting the documentation at https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version

> There are advantages to turning it off, and most applications will be unaffected if it is turned off. For that reason, *****all applications are encouraged to switch this setting off on every database connection as soon as that connection is opened.*****

what's the advantages?

Comment: With that setting turned off, it's harder for an attacker to arrange for malicious code to be run by an innocent-looking query.

Comment: See https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/10759e27d2